# Cannot display data in d3.js from local csv file

Tags: d3.js

I know that the question has been largely covered but I am still stuck with it so any help is more than appreciated. 
I am trying to display some data from a csv file locally on my computer in d3.js script but nothing is displayed. I have tried two solutions so far:

**Solution 1:**

Some of the answers found online state that the solution is to install a local server. So I installed a portable version of Uniform Server UPX (because I don't have the administrator privileges to install node http server on my computer). 
But even when I run the server from the directory where my index.html is located, nothing happens. Here is the code I am using for reading data from the csv file:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
      .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});
```

Furthermore, this solution isn't convenient for me because I want the data to be updated automatically from the csv file without having to run a cmd prompt to start the http server...

**Solution2**

I tried to allow the browser access local files by adding the following line in my head index, without success either:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"/>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<style>
```

Could you please point out what I should do to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saving the files in the "www" folder? Do you see "localhost" in the browser panel?

Comment: Yes I do see the localhost in my browser. I put the data.csv file in the www file too and changed the d3.csv callback function as follows but it didn't work: d3.csv("http://localhost:8080/data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

Comment: If it is in the same folder, try using just "data.csv", drop the "localhost.8080/" part.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I did eveything as you mentioned but the problem persists. Any other idea please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is happening... Maybe you can try another server, like WampServer.